# How to correctly test a component with several divs displaying values, from an object, that could possibly have duplicates

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have been following *React Testing Library and Jest: The Complete Guide* by Stephen Grider on [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-testing-library-and-jest/). In lecture 58 I noticed that one of his solutions for a test would actually fail.

The example he gives is that we're testing a small component that 'someone else' has written, and that it is advisable to not adjust their code. The component recieves an object from its parent and displays 4 divs with values from said object.

This is the component:

```
const RepositoriesSummary = ({ repository }) => {
  const { stargazers_count, open_issues, forks, language } = repository;

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-row gap-4 text-gray-700">
      <div>
        <StarIcon aria-label="stars" size={16} /> {stargazers_count}
      </div>
      <div>{open_issues} issues need help</div>
      <div>{forks} Forks</div>
      <div>{language}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RepositoriesSummary;
```

This is the test that Stephen wrote out. I adjusted values to confirm failure:

```
test("displays correct information about the repository", () => {
  const repository = {
    stargazers_count: 12,
    open_issues: 12,
    forks: 30,
    language: "JS",
  };

  render(<RepositoriesSummary repository={repository} />);

  for (let key in repository) {
    const value = repository[key];
    const element = screen.getByText(new RegExp(value));
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();
  }
});
```

The test would fail because `stargazers_count` and `open_issues` have the same values.

So in this instance, what would be the correct way to test this component?

Stephen mentioned that it's not ideal to adjust the component's code. How true is this?

Comment: Test the _whole content_ of the div. `12 issues need help` won't get mixed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can be more specific with your test assertions by checking for the full string you expectthe user to see instead of looping over the values and looking for partial matches:

```
test("displays correct information about the repository", () => {
  const repository = {
    stargazers_count: 12,
    open_issues: 12,
    forks: 30,
    language: "JS",
  };

  render(<RepositoriesSummary repository={repository} />);

  const stargazersCount = getByText(repository.stargazers_count);
  const openIssues = getByText(`${repository.open_issues} issues need help`);
  const forks = getByText(`${repository.forks} Forks`);
  const language = getByText(repository.language);
  
  expect(stargazersCount).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(openIssues).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(stargaforks).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(language).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

If you want to make it a bit shorter you can just call the `getBy...` methods like so:

```
getByText(repository.stargazers_count);
getByText(`${repository.open_issues} issues need help`);
getByText(`${repository.forks} Forks`);
getByText(repository.language);
```

In react testing library, all `getBy...` methods will cause the test to fail if they are unable to find the value you passed to them so they already implicitly making the assertion that the text was found. You just need to be careful not to use the same approach with `queryBy...` methods because they don't cause the test to fail because they return `null` when unable to find the value passed to them.

The main reason for using an explicit assertion `expect(...).toBeInTheDocument()` is that it's nice for readability.

Comment: This is great :) however, if `repository.forks` does not have the string 'Forks' and has the same value as `repository.stargazers_count`. What would be the approach then?

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the test. What you are essentially testing is that the values you pass to the component are being displayed. When you pass 2 identical values your test doesn't fail because the component is not displaying the correct values, it fails because RTL found more than 1 matching result, so you aren't really achieving any testing benefit by over-engineering the test so it accounts for every possible **testing** scenario

Comment: Okay, yeah that makes total sense :D thanks for your response, really appreciate it!